# Executing stored procedure as windows authenticated user - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

I have some user:
`(UserName, Password) = (windowUser, windowUser)`
I am able to login via Window Authenticated mode and execute `someProcedure`.

I have also some other SQL Authorized user - `sqlUser1`.
I would like to be able to execute `someProcedure` as `windowUser`.

I don't want to use `sql job`, because I have some parameters for this procedure and I won't to pass it by table.

Is there exists some way to do this ?

Comment: Just this one procedure, or all procedures for the DB/schema?

Comment: Just this one. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly grant execute permissions on this procedure (object) like so:

`GRANT EXECUTE ON someProcedure TO sqlUser1`

Comment: It returns error that I must use Window authenticated user. (it is invoking ssis packages)

Comment: @JavaNewbie you stated you wanted to execute the procedure via a SQL Authentication account, not Windows Authentication. This statement allows that. There are [blogs available](http://thinknook.com/execute-ssis-via-stored-procedure-ssis-2012-2012-08-13/) stating that you must uses a Windows Authentication account for SSIS. Your original question didn't address this requirement.[One potential work around](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80507/issues-with-module-signing-and-ssis-catalog-internal-procedures)